# Uploading a video to parse server , using the Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, video-capture, android-camera-intent

I am trying to upload a video to parse server using the camera intent to capture the videos.
the code is as follows.  Now my problem is that the video is getting played in the videoView using the videoUri, BUT its not getting uploaded to the server. I am getting a FileNotFoundException saying that     "there exists no such file or directory",
Example:-
I/info: content://media/external/video/media/57463       //this is the Log output for videoUri//
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/video/media/57463 (No such file or directory)
Can somebody please help with this issue??

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
Uri videoUri,vUri;
ParseUser currentUser;
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    Button captureVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureVideo);
    videoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Button saveButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    //save Button clicks handled here.
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(videoUri!=null){
               Log.i("info", ""+videoUri);
                byte[] bytes = convertVideoToBytes(videoUri);
                //now lets try and add this uri file to the parse server in a parsefile.
                ParseFile parseVideoFile = new ParseFile("video.mp4", bytes);
                parseVideoFile.saveInBackground();
                currentUser.put("video", parseVideoFile);
                currentUser.saveInBackground();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this,"No Video to save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //capture video button click is handled here.
    captureVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    });
}
    //onActivityResult is shown here.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            videoUri = intent.getData();
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            videoView.start();

        }
    }

//this is to convert the videoUri to byte[] arrays.

public static byte[] convertVideoToBytes( Uri videoUri) {
        byte[] videoBytes = null;
        File inputFile=new File(videoUri.getPath());
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
            int n;
            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                baos.write(buf, 0, n);

            videoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return videoBytes;
}
```

}

Comment: `content://media/external/video/media/57463` That is a nice content scheme. An uri.

Comment: `/external/video/media/57463` That is the last part of your content scheme. It is no file system path so the File and FileOutputSteam classes can not be used on it.

Comment: Instead of opening a FileInputStream on a part of an uri you open an InputStream for the uri itself. Then read from the InputStream in the same way as it was a FileInputStream.

Comment: `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

Comment: thank you so much, the code worked like a charm. i was able to upload the video to the parse server, though now i have to try and download it back from the server and play the video back in my app..if you have a solution for this also? can you please share?

Comment: I am getting the data in the form of byte array and i have to convert it back to Uri to be able to play in the videoView.

Comment: You have to save the bytes to file and then use a FileProvider to lett another app play it. Or obtain an uri from the media store and write the bytes to that uri and then give the player that uri.

Comment: @blackapps : Hi again I have been trying to get the byte array from the server and play it in the videoView but without any success. Can u please share the code for this.I have obtained an uri from the mediastore but i am having issues with writing the bytes to that uri.

Comment: You can open an outputstream for that uri on the same way as you opened an inputstream. See my comment. Then write.

Comment: @blackapps : hi..hope u r fine..I have used the following code to download the byte array and write them to an uri and play it in the videoView but the player only displays the first frame of the video and stops there. I am not able to play the complete video and moreover there is no error being displayed. –

Answer (score 0):

here is my code..sorry for posting it as an answer but i didnt know how to post the code.

```
      public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      VideoView finalView;
      Button button_play;
      ParseUser currentUser;
      String videoString;
      Uri videoUri,contentUri, fileProvider;
      File videoFile;
      public final String APP_TAG = "MyCustomApp";
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
      finalView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.finalview);
      button_play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);

   
      // Create a File reference for future access
      videoFile = getVideoFileUri();
      fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ViewActivity.this,
            "com.codepath.fileprovider", videoFile);
    
      currentUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
      ParseFile parseFile = (ParseFile)currentUser.get("videos");
      parseFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            try {
                 videoUri=convertBytesToUri(data,fileProvider);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    button_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finalView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            finalView.start();
        }
    });
}
    public Uri convertBytesToUri(byte[] data,Uri fileProvider) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os=getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileProvider);

    os.write(data);
    os.flush();
    return   fileProvider;
    }
    // Returns the File for a photo stored on disk given the fileName
    public File getVideoFileUri() {
    // Get safe storage directory for photos
    // Use `getExternalFilesDir` on Context to access package-specific directories.
    // This way, we don't need to request external read/write runtime permissions.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), 
    APP_TAG);
    //Let's create a unique fileName.
    String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fileName=timeStamp+".mp4";
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }

    // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
    File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);

    return file;
}
```

Comment: `if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }` That should be: `if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory"); return null;
    }`. And the caller should check for null.